# boundary regularity for the lipschitz continuity of the projection

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
I would like that, close to $\partial\Omega$, the euclidean projection
on the boundary to be well-defined and Lipschitz.
More precisely, that it exists $\eta>0$ such that, on
$\Omega_\eta:=\{x\in\Omega;dist(x,\partial\Omega)<\eta\}$, the map

$x\mapsto P(x)$, with $P(x)$ the unique point in $\partial\Omega$ s.t. $dist(x,\partial\Omega)=|x-P(x)|$

is well-defined and Lipschitz continuous.

My question is: what is the (least) regularity needed for $\partial\Omega$
in order to have this? I have been told that it should be of class $C^2$ but i cannot find the argument...